# Java Networking Music streaming UDP or TCP

Tags: java, networking, tcp, network-programming, udp

I want to make an application that lets me stream music from my *server* app to my *client* app.
I'm not really sure if I need to use `UDP` or `TCP`?

Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: If you have that little to start with, you really have no business making an application. I'm not trying to be mean, but this question is really like, "I want to build a suspension bridge over a river to carry cars and trucks. What kind of steel do I need? Or can I use cement?" If the task is that large and the question that unfocused, something is really wrong.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Hobby, I guess. dumazy, you should try them both out, see the differences for yourself.

Comment: @dumazy Have you figured out some pros and cons for each by yourself? Share them with us, maybe we can add to them, so you can make a sensible decision.

Comment: Well, UDP doesn't guarantee that the data will be delivered properly, but also works a lot faster. I heard that UDP is used a lot for stuff like gaming, where the transfer speed is very important. TCP does guarantee that the data will be delivered but also takes some more time. I'm not really sure if the audio can get messed up when some of the data wasn't transfered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UDP` is more suitable for streaming media. But if you are sensitive with your "*music*" streaming, **TCP** is more secure.. it requires more "*handshake*" between the server and the client.

Comment: TCP is not more secure than UDP.  TCP is more reliable than UDP.  A three-way-handshake has nothing to do with security. Its just a way of setting up a connection. UDP is used when data becomes "stale" in a short period of time, and when missing some of the data isn't greatly important. This is why its used in gaming and music, missing a small piece the stream isn't important, but getting that data somewhere quickly *IS* important.